# Can I create an image with a specific size in bytes?

Tags: images, image-conversion, media-creation-tool

I want to create an image file so it's exactly 5MB for testing purposes. Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? (It may affect the answers.)

Comment: @MikeBrockington I'm testing website security where upload limit is 5mb

Comment: So do you really need a genuine image file for this, or just a 5mb bunch of zeroes, with a   `.jpeg` file extension?

Comment: I find the term  `image file` very broad. You can copy a HDD to an `.iso` file. Wouldn't that be an image file, too? You mean a graphics file.

Comment: fallocate can create exact filesizes.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with compression specifically? If so please explain, and if not, please remove the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use the image metadata. jpg supports exif data. You mentioned php, which can write raw exif data with [`iptcembed()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iptcembed.php). Generate a string of null bytes (binary 0) long enough to pad out the file

```
<?php
$path = '/path/to/image.jpg';
$size = filesize($path);
$goal = 1024 * 1024 * 5; //5MB
$zeros = str_pad("", $goal - $size, "\0"); // make a string of ($goal - $size) binary 0s
$paddedImage = iptcembed($zeros, $path);
file_put_contents("/path/to/padded-image.jpg", $paddedImage);
```

Comment: The idea of binary nuls is fine, but in reality any data after the end of the file is fine.  One may even append multiple copies of the file to itself to reach the required size.

Comment: @Criggie gotcha, I'm not as familiar with how trailing data is handled in images. In this case, since its writing exif data and not just trailing data, I like the binary nulls so you don't end up with corrupt exif data

Comment: Case in point: rarjpeg. It's an image file spliced with a rar file, each program only reads its own part.

Answer (score 26):

Most implementations of image formats ignore trailing zeros. Therefore, it is relatively straightforward to pad a file to a desired size. (5 megabytes is 10240 blocks.)

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

print_usage_and_exit(){
  echo "Usage: $0 FILE BLOCKS"
  echo "This script will pad FILE with zeros up to BLOCKS."
  echo "FILE must not already be larger than BLOCKS."
  exit
}
FILE=$1
BLOCKS=$2
if [ -z $FILE ] || [ -z $BLOCKS ] || [ -z "${BLOCKS##*[!0-9]*}" ]; then
  print_usage_and_exit
fi
FILE_SIZE=$(stat $FILE | awk '/Blocks:/ { print $4 }')
SIZE_DIFFERENCE=$(($BLOCKS-$FILE_SIZE))
if [ $SIZE_DIFFERENCE -le 0 ]; then
  print_usage_and_exit
fi
dd if=/dev/zero iflag=append count=$SIZE_DIFFERENCE >> $FILE 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Some image formats also have metadata areas, in which I assume data can also be added to pad out the size

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Is this php? I get an error, parse error "syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)"

Comment: @JohnDoe it's not PHP, it's a shell script for bash as indicated by the first line.

Comment: Is a bash script, look at the shebang line https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang

Comment: @JohnDoe the script was written for linux. it could be run on windows with [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) but that's kind of a lot of setup just to run one script.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow thanks for you reply, can script be written for windows? Do you know what could I search on google to find it?

Comment: @JohnDoe Since you aim to do some security testing, you could show a bit of willingness to learn something new and set up a Linux VM to run the script there.

Comment: No need for a full-blown VM. Just install cygwin shell and you are good. If you work with git, you might even already have a shell as the standard git shell on windows is a minGW based bash.

Comment: The idea of binary nuls is fine, but in reality any data after the end of the file is fine.  One may even append multiple copies of the file to itself to reach the required size.

Comment: @MechMK1 at least JohnDoe did ask what to google for.

Answer (score 8):

Few other answers calculate how many trailing zeros you need to append, then they append. In Linux there's this simple way:

```
truncate -s 5MB image
```

(this assumes you want 5 MB, i.e. 5*1000*1000 bytes. For 5 MiB, i.e. 5*1024*1024 bytes, use `-s 5M`).

If originally `image` is larger than the specified size, then the extra data will be lost. If originally `image` is smaller, then padding zeros will be added. Added fragment will be sparse, if possible.

If for any reason you don't want sparseness, use `fallocate`:

```
fallocate -l 5MB image
```

(similarly, yet not identically: `-l 5MB` for 5 MB, `-l 5MiB` for 5 MiB).

`fallocate` used this way can only extend `image`. If the file is already at least that big then its size won't change (sparseness can change, I won't elaborate).

Answer (score 4):

if you insist on Windows - I suggest going to CMD , find a suitable small file ...

`>copy /B file1+file1 file2` while replacing file1 and file2 with suitable filenames .. you can repeat said copy command by using file2 as source (first 2 names) .. the files will be binary concatenated - so you get a target file of increasing size - until you are satisfied

not as nice as a script - but it works out of the (windows)-box only needs 1 source file .. that doesn't even necessarily has to be an image - as mime-type for uploads mostly is determined by the file-ending

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be any specific format? For instance, would a BMP file do?

Uncompressed BMP files are exactly that: completely uncompressed. Thus, each pixel takes up a fixed amount of storage, so it's just a matter of working backwards from the file size you want to the dimensions of the image. So, for an 8-bit BMP, *in theory* you'd need a 5 megapixel image to get a 5 megabyte file.

Unfortunately, there are a few things that complicate the calculation somewhat:

1. You're going to have to take the size of the BMP header into account. There are several different versions of the format, each with a different header size, so you'll need to experiment with your image editor to figure out what size header it produces.
2. Each line of the image is padded to be a multiple of four bytes, so there might be a few extra bytes per line.
3. BMP files can be compressed, indexed, and have color profile information included. These options are rarely used, but they are out there. If your graphics program uses these and you can't turn them off, your size calculation is going to get a lot more complicated (if it's even possible at all).

Answer (score 1):

One can use https://iamtester.ru/ (gratis):

[image]

Example with bytes = 700000 (i.e., 700 KB) and type = PNG:

> [image]

FYI, related: [Make a GIF image with an exact given byte size](https://superuser.com/q/1809037/116475).