# Make a GIF image with an exact given byte size

Tags: imagemagick, firmware, image-editing, file-format, gif

For a specific task (replace an image inside a firmware without any data offset shifting), I need to create a GIF file of size 409x240 pixels of exactly 6449 bytes:

- offset 0-5: `GIF89a` (magic string)
- ...
- offset 6447-6448: hex `00 3B`

When I created such a GIF with, for example MSPaint, the output is ~ 2 KB, which is too small.

Question: is there a way to modify a GIF file to take a larger given size? Can we do null-byte (hex `00`) padding near the end of the GIF file? Maybe with ImageMagick, or directly with a HEX editor (I already have one)?

Comment: Does the actual contents matter? Your question suggests not so you could simply use a tool to expand the file to the correct size https://superuser.com/questions/299329/resize-a-file-in-command-prompt and the remaining data would simply be zeroes.

Comment: Or add a comment: https://superuser.com/questions/556315/gif-image-exif-tags

Comment: @Mokubai, Yes the actual contents matter (a logo picture). I can easily expand a given 2 KB .gif file by adding zero-bytes at the end. But then it won't be a correct GIF file. For example a GIF has to end with `3B` hex or `00 3B` hex (I need to check). There are maybe other conditions to make a valid GIF file.

Comment: @Berend not really, https://superuser.com/questions/556315/gif-image-exif-tags is about EXIF metadata tags, whereas I need to expand the actual file-size in byte to a given size.

Comment: I would think that filesize increases when adding a comment?

Comment: Ohhh you're right @Berend, I didn't think about this :) Sorry, my bad! I thought you were speaking about setting a "size" metadata to a bigger value :)

Comment: If Berand's good suggestion doesn't work, let me know, and I'll write an answer for another possible technique (using a long comment field should be easier though).

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I'm interested in the other solution too, because I'm not 100% sure that the firmware's built-in (very small) GIF decoder executable is able to parse GIF that contain EXIF metadata. It's possible that the firmware only works with non-EXIF GIF. By the way, the original image has no metadata, IIRC.

Comment: Okay, writing now...

Comment: @Basj but your actual gif data will contain the right ending and content. If you are only padding out the ending because you need to fill a certain area in flash or firmware then the net effect will be the same, a padded block of data. If the size of the file absolutely matters then presumably the next block is read from a specific address and how the previous block is filled could well be irrelevant. So create your file, use the commands listed in the question I linked to pad the file ending, and then insert it into your firmware. You get a valid gif and the padding to the next block of data.

Comment: @Mokubai I tested to insert zero bytes just before the last byte (`3B`) so that this byte remains the last one. It works, at least with various software on PC. I hope it'll work the same on the firmware. I should also try your idea to pad the zeros after the last byte, maybe it could work as well...

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would try is to pad the GIF file with `null`s.  You can first try to simply append with a sufficient number of `null`s.  If that doesn't work, you can try adding the `null`s immediately before the GIF file's final block terminator.

You can also try creating an XMP comment as recommended by Berend and discussed here: https://superuser.com/a/556337/380110

Now, if none of the above work, here's another possibility.  We don't have your actual image file, so I can't guarantee this will work, but it's certainly worth a try.

GIF images support LZW compression at different compression levels.  Thus, you can modify the level of compression of the file to try to get it to be the exact size you want.

I'm not sure what compression (if any) MS Paint is using to generate your 2KB file, but here's the procedure I would try:

1. Upload your image to: https://www.freeconvert.com/gif-compressor
2. Click on "GIF Options".
3. Select "Undo Optimizations".
4. Save the GIF file locally.
5. See what size the file is to determine if you now need to increase or decrease its file size.
6. Using that same web-app, adjust the LZW compression level to adjust the file size.  You can also adjust the number of colors, if needed.

If you don't get quite the file size you need, you can tweak a few pixels in your image to yield the desired result.  Remember, for compression, the LZW algorithm is largely looking for similar blocks of pixels.  So if you intentionally make blocks of pixels dissimilar, it will increase the file size.  This doesn't need to be a visible change.  A slightly different color for a single pixel will likely be undetectable by anyone without a magnifying glass.  You can make slightly different changes in numerous areas without any visible difference, but it will increase the file size.

You can also ensure your image uses a complete palette of 256 unique colours.  This will make the file much larger.  Again, you can do this creatively to hide that fact that you are using more unique colours than are actually needed to render your image.

Comment: I inserted null bytes just before the last byte, so that the last byte remains `3B` (which marks the end of a GIF file). It works at least with various viewers. Now, finger crossed that it'll work in the firmware too!

Comment: Great! I hope it works!  Let me know.